# Query and get one-to-one related tables from schema metadata that exists within a schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-one

How to query and find out one-to-one related tables in a schema from database metadata information. onetoone relationship established by primary and foreign key or by unique constraints whatever possible for one-to-one.

Tried writing a stored procedure but getting irrelevant resultsets. This stored procedure will create a 'onetoone_table' with results. Expecting to get tablename, columnname, referencedtablename and referencedcolumnname by passing schemaname as inputvalue. But i get irrelevant and duplicate records which are not onetoone. Pls suggest.

```
with cte as (SELECT b.TABLE_NAME, b.COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*) as Total   
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
        WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = ''' + @schemaName + ''' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN (''PRIMARY KEY'', ''FOREIGN KEY'')
    ) a
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE b ON a.Table_Name = b.Table_Name
        AND a.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = b.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
        AND a.CONSTRAINT_NAME = b.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        AND a.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = B.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    GROUP BY b.TABLE_NAME, b.COLUMN_NAME
    HAVING COUNT(b.TABLE_NAME) > 1)
    SELECT a.Table_Name, a.Column_Name, a.Referenced_Table_Name, a.Referenced_Column_Name
    INTO onetoone_table
    FROM (
        SELECT a.name AS table_name, b.name AS column_name, c.name AS referenced_table_name, d.name AS referenced_column_name
        FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk
        INNER JOIN sys.tables a ON fk.parent_object_id = a.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns b ON fk.parent_object_id = b.object_id AND fk.parent_column_id = b.column_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables c ON fk.referenced_object_id = c.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns d ON fk.referenced_object_id = d.object_id AND fk.referenced_column_id = d.column_id
    ) a
    INNER JOIN cte b ON a.Column_Name = b.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE a.Referenced_Table_Name IS NOT NULL
        AND a.Table_Name IN (
            SELECT table_name 
            FROM cte 
            GROUP BY table_name 
            HAVING COUNT(table_name) = 1 
        );
```

Comment: "but am getting inaccurate values", please show the results you are getting and the results you are expecting to get so we can understand what "inaccurate" means.

Comment: Thats right. I mean to say i get some irrelevant mappings but they are not actually onetoone related. Also I have not added logic to include onetoone related tables by unique constraints since am not sure how to get it done using metadata

Comment: Still need to see example data and desired results.

Comment: You should be using better aliases than `a` and `b` for `tables` and `columns` respectively - and using `c` for `tables` is just rage-inducing.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add the table definitions of a couple of tables with their fks to demonstrate the issue you're having since people don't sit in front of your database.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to work out what is wrong with your existing query, but you are not taking into account multi-column foreign keys, nor multi-column indexes. In fact, you are only taking into account single-column *constraints*, but some indexes are unique also.

You also shouldn't use `INFROMATION_SCHEMA` as it's for compatibility and can be unreliable.

We can `APPLY` a resultset looking for unique indexes of each table, where all the columns have a matching foreign key column in the particular foreign key we are looking at. This then tells us that the foreign-key relationship is unique on this side (in other words, even if not all FK columns are in in the index, it is still unique).

This is essentially relational division, except that we only need at least one match. So you can do it in an `APPLY` with a `TOP 1` or do it in an `EXISTS`.

```sql
SELECT
  parent.name AS table_name,
  referenced.name AS referenced_table_name,
  ParentColumns.*,
  RefColumns.*
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
JOIN sys.tables parent ON fk.parent_object_id = parent.object_id
JOIN sys.tables referenced ON fk.referenced_object_id = referenced.object_id

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      IndexName = iParent.name,
      UniquColumnCount = COUNT(*),
      UniqueColumns = STRING_AGG(cParent.name, ', ')
    FROM sys.indexes iParent
    JOIN sys.index_columns icParent
      ON icParent.object_id = iParent.object_id
     AND icParent.index_id = iParent.index_id
     AND icParent.is_included_column = 0
    JOIN sys.columns cParent
      ON cParent.object_id = iParent.object_id
     AND cParent.column_id = icParent.column_id

    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
      ON icParent.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
     AND fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    
    WHERE iParent.is_unique = 1
      AND iParent.object_id = fk.parent_object_id

    GROUP BY
      iParent.index_id, iParent.name
    HAVING COUNT(fkc.constraint_object_id) = COUNT(*)  -- all matches
) ParentColumns

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      IndexName = iRef.name,
      UniquColumnCount = COUNT(*),
      UniqueColumns = STRING_AGG(cRef.name, ', ')
    FROM sys.indexes iRef
    JOIN sys.index_columns icRef
      ON icRef.object_id = iRef.object_id
     AND icRef.index_id = iRef.index_id
     AND icRef.is_included_column = 0
    JOIN sys.columns cRef
      ON cRef.object_id = iRef.object_id
     AND cRef.column_id = icRef.column_id

    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
      ON icRef.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
     AND fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    
    WHERE iRef.is_unique = 1
      AND iRef.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id

    GROUP BY
      iRef.index_id, iRef.name
    HAVING COUNT(fkc.constraint_object_id) = COUNT(*)  -- all matches
) RefColumns;
```